# Отделить слова регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Я пытаюсь получить регулярным выражением второе слово.

Вот такой текст я имею:

```css
@import "vars";
@import "fonts";
@import "global";
@import "dddd";
// ============================
:root {
    --fs: 2vw;
}

$red: red;
body {
    // @include f500;
    font-family: 'Museo Cyrl 500';
    font-size: var(--fs);
    // font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 27px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #838383;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Я хочу получить следующее в массив:
`[vars],[fonts],[global],[dddd]`

Вот что я написал:
В переменную `str` я написал похожий текст для тестирования.
Тот текст "выше" я считываю через nodejs из файла.

```js
const regexp = /@import\s([^\w])/g;
let str = '@import "vars"; @import "dwada"; dwdw wddwa fgfff aaaaa'
let result = str.matchAll(regexp);
let exit = Array.from(result);
let firstMatch = exit[0];
console.log(firstMatch[0])
```

Но мне возвращается совсем другое: **`@import "`**
Как составить данное регулярное выражение правильно? Подскажите пожалусто.

Comment: Расшифруйте свой шаблон `\s` - любой пробельный символ, `[^\w]` - любой символ отличный от диапазона латинских букв, цифр и знака нижнего подчеркивания, как раз кавычка подходит. `@import\s"?\w+` попробуйте что нибудь такое

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Nf5S8l/1/ - удобный сервис для составления регулярных выражений. В данном случае выражение `(?<=@import ")\w+(?=")` должно удовлетворить потребность

Comment: Я думал кавычка ^ Соответствует началу ввода. Исходя из статьи. (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-caret)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const regexp = /@import\s+["']([^"']+)["'];/gi;
const str = `
  @import "vars";
  @import "fonts";
  @import "global";
  @import "dddd";
  dwdw wddwa fgfff aaaaa
`;
const result = str.matchAll(regexp);

// получение массива строк со значениями из первой группы рег.выражения:
const matchGroupValues = [...result].map(([, group1]) => group1);
console.log(matchGroupValues);  // ['vars', 'fonts', 'global', 'dddd']

// оборачивание полученных значений в массивы, как написано в вопросе:
const valuesInArrays = matchGroupValues.map(value => [value]);
console.log(valuesInArrays);    // [['vars'], ['fonts'], ['global'], ['dddd']]
```

Составляющие рег. выражения:

- `@import` - буквально эта последовательность символов
- `\s+` - как минимум один пробельный символ
- `["']` - ровно один символ кавычек (либо `"`, либо `'`)
- `([^"']+)` - захват (в первую группу) любых символов кроме `"` и `'`, как минимум один такой "некавычковый" символ

Квантификатор `+` ("одно или больше") жадный по-умолчанию, поэтому в группу захвата результата попадает максимально возможное количество "некавычковых" символов входной строки. Аналогично и с пробелами: с данным квантификатором, токену `\s` будет соответствовать как можно большее количество пробельных символов.

Завершающая часть выражения `["'];` необязательна, работать будет и без нее: в пример эта часть добавлена только для лучшего понимания рег.выражений (с этой частью, выражение целиком описывает statement с директивой `@import`).

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь! Всю ночь тупил сидел не мог написать, как встану на свежую голову разберусь, как оно работает.

Comment: @Артем, пожалуйста. Раз не совсем понятно как работает, я добавил текстовое описание после примера.

Comment: Да оно добавило больше ясности. Спасибо вам за добавленное описание!